# SMTP connection disconnecting after giving message Authorizing to server, working with james server and outlook

Tags: outlook, smtp, outlook-addin, smtp-auth, james

I am working with Apache James 2.3 and while Outlook tries to send emails to the server. I get the below smtp conversation and then the connection closes. I have configured the Outlook with the required authentication credentials.

But I still seems to not be able to pinpoint where is it going wrong, as I am only able to get the connection is initiated log on the James server side and no Mailets are being hit.

```
 Port: 587, Secure: TLS, SPA: no
 Finding host
 Connecting to host
 Connected to host
 <rx> 220 XXXX SMTP Server (JAMES SMTP Server) ready Thu, XXXXXXXXX 08:39:20 +0000 (GMT)
 [tx] EHLO XXXXXXXXXXX
 <rx> 250-XXXX Hello XXXXXXXXXXX (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX])
 <rx> 250-SIZE 102400000
 <rx> 250-STARTTLS
 <rx> 250-PIPELINING
 <rx> 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
 Securing connection
 [tx] STARTTLS
 <rx> 220 Go ahead
 Securing connection
 Connected to host
 [tx] EHLO XXXXXXXXXXX
 <rx> 250-XXXX Hello XXXXXXXXXXX (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX])
 <rx> 250-SIZE 102400000
 <rx> 250-STARTTLS
 <rx> 250-PIPELINING
 <rx> 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
 Authorizing to server
 Disconnecting from host
 Disconnected from host
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server does not advertise any authentication mechanisms - there is no 250-AUTH reply to EHLO.